# Where is the default camera?

Tags: opengl

I've read that if I don't initialize it, OpenGL uses the default camera.

What configuration have this camera?  I've been trying with some basic triangles and it looks like the camera is in `0,0,1` facing `0,0,0`, I assume that the Up vector is `0,1,0`.

Can someone tell me if this is correct? And is there any way to change the default camera settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenGL has no "camera". If you do not use any transformations (or all transformation matrices are the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix)), then you have to specify the vertex coordinates in normalized device space.
The normalized device space is a unique cube, with the left, bottom, near of (-1, -1, -1) and the right, top, far of (1, 1, 1).
Hence the first component of the vertex coordinate (x) defines the position from the left (-1) to the right (1). The 2nd component (y) defines the position form the bottom (-1) to the top (1) and the 3rd component (z) defines the depth form near (-1) to far (1).
Thus the "up-vector" is (0, 1, 0).

In common each mesh of the scene is transformed by the model matrix, the view matrix and the projection matrix. Finally the projected scene is mapped to the viewport.

The projection, view and model matrix interact together to present the objects (meshes) of a scene on the viewport.
The model matrix defines the position orientation and scale of a single object (mesh) in the world space of the scene.
The view matrix defines the position and viewing direction of the observer (viewer) within the scene.
The projection matrix defines the area (volume) with respect to the observer (viewer) which is projected onto the viewport.

If you talk about the "camera", then you mean the view matrix. The view matrix transforms a vertex coordinate from world space to view space. If you want a different world coordinate system, then you have to define an appropriate view matrix.